# Microsoft Surface Book 2 with external displays

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, displays

A few months ago I invested in 3x 4K displays 3x(3840x2160). They have connectivity for HDMI and DisplayPort 1.2

What might sound crazy is that I don't have a workstation to drive them, so currently I'm driving two of them from my work laptop.

I want to invest in a Microsoft Surface Book 2 but I fear this lacks the connectivity I require for external displays, plus I'm not sure whether a discrete GTX 1050 /w 2GB GDDR5 will be sufficient for the displays, *and that's only if I buy the top of the range model.*

Is there anything like the [Razer Core v2](https://www.razerzone.com/gb-en/gaming-laptops/razer-core-v2) external graphics unit that I can get for the surface book?

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR: You'll need a different laptop. More info on your requirements would be good so I can make a better reccomendation.

#### Natively

Right out of the gate, [Microsoft says no.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4039635/connect-surface-to-a-tv-display-or-projector)

```
Surface            | External displays | Max refresh rate | Max screen resolution
–––––––––––––––––––|–––––––––––––––––––|––––––––––––––––––|––––––––––––––––––––––
Surface Book 2 15” | One               | 60 Hz            | 4096 x 2304
Surface Book 2 15” | Two               | 30 Hz            | 4096 x 2304
Surface Book 2 15” | Two               | 60 Hz            | 2560 x 1600
```

But I'm not one to believe Microsoft. After all, [it is a DisplayPort 1.4 signal being carried by that USB-C connector in theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode_partner_specifications), [supporting up to an 8K@60Hz signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Resolution_and_refresh_frequency_limits_for_DisplayPort), [as confirmed by the GTX 1060 specs](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-1060/specifications). 3x4K@60Hz should be no biggie, right?

Problem: How does one connect up three displays using one connector? Answer: [With an MST hub!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Multiple_displays_on_single_DisplayPort_connector) Problem: Every MST hub I know of is DisplayPort 1.2 rated, and can't support 3x4k@even 30Hz–[even ones advertised for the (admittedly last gen) Surface products.](https://www.accellcables.com/products/ultraav-mini-displayport-1-2-mst-multi-display-hub) (I've personally tested this one myself with a Surface Pro 4 and 2x1440p@60Hz.) Even the official [Surface Dock](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/accessories/surface-dock) only has two Mini DisplayPort connectors.

So while it may be possible, Microsoft certainly won't support it, and the hardware doesn't exist as far as I know.

#### eGPU

USB-C is one of those confusing things: it refers both to a physical connector and a communications protocol. Though Thunderbolt 3 uses USB-C type connectors, they are not one and the same. The Surface Book 2 does not support Thunderbolt 3 (or any other Thunderbolt revision), and therefore cannot support eGPUs.

#### What now?

Without knowing your budget, use case, and the features you want, it's kinda hard to recommend a laptop. However, based off the fact that you like the Surface Book, I'll recommend the [Eve V](https://eve-tech.com/pages/eve-v) with an [Akitio Node](https://www.akitio.com/expansion/node) as your eGPU box. It's a direct competitor to the Surface Pro, and includes a Thunderbolt 3 port, so eGPU will work fine.

Obviously there's a lot of trade offs here: eGPUs are expensive (the Akitio Node is the cheapest reasonable box I know of and still costs $250) and [take a significant performance hit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHwXOwTgYB0), you won't get the relative safety in terms of warranty and support of an established brand like Microsoft with the Eve V (though [it was reviewed well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQm60PrrEJk&t=385s)), and the Eve V isn't an outstanding performer for every workload. But–based on the information you've given me (read: give me more info)–it's the best recommendation I can make.